# Create Button on existing model to download CSV data

Tags: csv, odoo, odoo-13

I have a function that generates a CSV report for `survey.survey`s to my employer's liking and I need a way to download that data. The issue I'm having is to get a button on the page to actually download the data, I've tried adding a controller but when I go to it, it says 404.

I'm using Odoo 13

Here's the controller I tried, but when i go to it, it returns a 404. Yes i checked my `__init__.py` for both my module and controllers folder

```py
class MyExport(http.Controller):

    @http.route(['/my_module/export/certs'], type='http', auth='user', methods=['GET'], website=True)
    def csv_download(self, **kw):
        csv = http.request.env['survey.survey'].generate_cert_report()

        filename = 'Certification Report - {}.csv'.format(
            datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

        headers = [
            ('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'),
            ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (filename))
        ]

        return request.make_response(csv, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You want to download all the answers of surveys right ?

Comment: As well as you can refer the base code for import file in accounting module for bank statement import.

Comment: I already have the code to generate the csv file, i just need to make the button download the file. I restarted my odoo service and that made it work, so i guess my question answers my question